# How to derive from "zealot"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

(Disclaimer: not only I tried googling the answer, I also asked native english speakers, but they couldn't give me a definitive answer).

Basically, In one of my conversations, I said the following sentence:

> They haven't contributed much to the world aside zealotness.

Then I got confused, and I realized I don't know what is the "derivative" for this word.

**hot** -> **heat**
**serious** -> **seriousness** 
**zealot** -> ???

Google remotely suggests **zealousness**, but it seems that this word actually backs-up the word "zealous" and not "zealot".

So, Is there an actual idiomatic way of saying "zealotness"

Comment: Don’t you just mean *zealotry* here?

Comment: perfect! post that as an answer and I'll mark it as an answer!

Comment: The rare *zelotism, zelotic*  also exist, as do special-use nouns like *zelator, zelatrix, zelatrice* — not to mention *zelophobia* and *zelotypia*, which are related but different because they're actually about the now-obsolete *zealousy* for *jealousy*.  To work up a full answer, one should delve into all of these, and I have to jump on a cross-country flight now. Perhaps someone else can cover all these today.

Comment: @tchrist I would strongly advise against jumping on cross-country flights. You might fall off, and it’s a long way down.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shortest noun from which *zealot* is derived is *zeal*. That is, both the person and the state of mind have direct precursors in Latin, which in turn borrowed them from Greek. Now, zeal has a slightly less specific connotation in modern English; but, brevity being the soul of wit, it will often do the job.

Where you truly need a more specific word, use the fairly common word *zealotry*.

I should advise against *zealotness*, which sounds as though the more idiomatic word(s) did not come to mind.

Comment: I know "zealotness" is not a real word, I just made it up in the heat of the conversation, realizing it's not a real word.

Comment: @DavidHaim: Oh, that wasn't aimed at you, just for future readers.